# Text not displaying correctly in page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, string

I'm passing a string of text "note" from javascript to my controller. In the controller I'm getting the "note" as a string and saving the "note" into the DB as a varchar(max) column. The problem I'm having is when I request the data to display on the page, the newlines are not formatting, so everything is on one line.

So here is what I do.

```
@Html.Raw(@note.Note.Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

I replace the newlines with a br and then wrap it in html.raw.
This works find until I insert text with special characters like this

> This "email" and any files transmitted with it are proprietary and intended solely for the use of the individual or '< ?' entity to whom they are addressed. If you have received this email in error please notify the system manager. Please note that any views or opinions presented in this #(*(#&)#*&$*(email are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of the company.

and then it gets screwed up!
What should I do here? Prevent all special characters? or is there something else I can do to read and display the charaters just like the user has entered them into the system?

Comment: Try this! `<span style="white-space: pre-line">@note.Note</span>`